# How to override ord behaivour in Python for str childs?

Tags: python, string, overriding

I have this class:

```
class STR(str):

    def __int__(self):
        return 42
```

If i use it in the promt like this:

```
>>> a=STR('8')
>>> ord(a)
56
>>> int(a)
42
>>> chr(a)
'*'
```

that's the behaivour. I'd like to ord(a) be 42. How can I do it? Which method should I override in the str class? Is all this documented anywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the C source for Python's builtin `ord` from the [current SVN revision of bltinmodule.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/bltinmodule.c?view=markup&pathrev=76648):

```
static PyObject *
builtin_ord(PyObject *self, PyObject* obj)
{
    long ord;
    Py_ssize_t size;

    if (PyString_Check(obj)) {
        size = PyString_GET_SIZE(obj);
        if (size == 1) {
            ord = (long)((unsigned char)*PyString_AS_STRING(obj));
            return PyInt_FromLong(ord);
        }
    } else if (PyByteArray_Check(obj)) {
        size = PyByteArray_GET_SIZE(obj);
        if (size == 1) {
            ord = (long)((unsigned char)*PyByteArray_AS_STRING(obj));
            return PyInt_FromLong(ord);
        }

#ifdef Py_USING_UNICODE
    } else if (PyUnicode_Check(obj)) {
        size = PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(obj);
        if (size == 1) {
            ord = (long)*PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(obj);
            return PyInt_FromLong(ord);
        }
#endif
    } else {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                 "ord() expected string of length 1, but " \
                 "%.200s found", obj->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }

    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
             "ord() expected a character, "
             "but string of length %zd found",
             size);
    return NULL;
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't make any method calls on the instance you pass in.  As far as I can tell, if you don't pass it an explicit string, there's no way to override the functionality of `ord`.

In fact, it's essentially verifying that the PyObject is either a string, byte array, or Unicode -- that's what the PyString_Check, etc. functions do.  If it's none of those, you get the TypeError exception.

One workaround that doesn't scale very well would be to write your own `ord` in the global namespace:

```
>>> class STR(str):
...     def __int__(self):
...             return 42
... 
>>> 
>>> def ord(s):
...     if isinstance(s, STR):
...             return int(s)
...     else:
...             return __builtins__.ord(s)
... 
>>>  
>>> ord(STR('fdsafds'))
42
>>> ord("!")
33
```

Of course, this scales horribly because another module using your class may be directly calling `__builtins__.ord`, or they might even be overwriting `ord` themselves!  But, if you only need this to work on a single, standalone module, this is one way to go about it.

Comment: I like this answer. Which is the scale problem? I can't see it very well.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody already posted the builtin  ord code, and there is no method call you may intercept.

One solution could be override the ord function, for example:

```
backup_ord = ord
def ord(obj):
    if hasattr(obj, '__ord__'):
        return obj.__ord__()
    else:
        return backup_ord(obj)
```

Then you define your class with the `__ord__` method and do something like:

```
class MyStr(str):
    def __ord__(self):
        return 'LOL'
```

For tests:

```
normal_five = '5'
strange_five = MyStr('5')
print ord(normal_five)
print ord(strange_five)
```

Outputs:

```
53
LOL
```

Answer (score 0):

`ord` is not overloadable, it doesn't call any method on string objects (at least in CPython - `Python/bltinmodule.c`, `builtin_ord` function).

The best way is probably to create `STR.ord` method and call that instead of the built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override ord but you can overwrite as variable for example

backup original ord

```
origord= ord

def ord(x):
    return 42


ord(a)
42

origord(a)
56
```

But I think its not good a idea to overwrite it.

Comment: :D but you know, it will confuse yourself and others people who read that codes later.